# Request method 'POST' is not supported with custom login page

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a custom login page form using Spring Boot MVC & Spring Security that uses a username and password.

However every time we do a submit, we get the following error after the user logins in, it's supposed to go to the main dashboard:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Method 'POST' is not supported.
> org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported"

I really appreciate anyone's help and guidance!

I have tired following this site: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login
and no matter the changes the error remains. Also sorry if I posted anything wrong this is my first-time using StackOverflow.

**This is the custom login page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--Refrences to CSS-->
    <link href="css/loginPage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    </head>
        <header>
        <a th:href="@{/}">GAZEBO HQ</a>
        </header>

    <body>
        <!--Login form Div-->
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
      <form class="LoginCont" th:action="@{/loginpage}" method="post">
        <div class="Login">
            <label for="uname"><b>UserName</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter UserName" name="uname" required/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required/>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="Selection">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember Me
            </label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="Create/Edit">
              <a th:href="@{/registration}">Register</a>
              <a>Forget Password?</a>
            </div>
    </form>
```

**Security config**

```java
package edu.sru.walters.EmployeeManagementSystem.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

//@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig// extends WebSecurityConfiguration {
    //Talks to the database
    @Autowired
    //private UserService userService;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
//Specify that URLs are allowed by anyone. With Authenticate(Login), any links not in here auto require authenticate
                .requestMatchers("/", "/index", "/loginpage","/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            //Login From reference 
            .formLogin() 
            //This indicates that we have a custom login page, instead of using the default login that comes with Spring Security
                .loginPage("/loginpage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginpage")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/");
            return http.build();        
    }
```

**POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>edu.sru.walters</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeManagementSystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeManagementSystem</name>
    <description>CPSC 488 Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**`MainController`**

```java
package edu.sru.walters.EmployeeManagementSystem.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import edu.sru.walters.EmployeeManagementSystem.models.Users;
import edu.sru.walters.EmployeeManagementSystem.repository.UserRepository;

//In this Class is our main controller that allows thymeleaf to locate and call web pages from the src/main/resources/templates folder, it also Requires the "@Controller" Tag
@Controller
public class MainController {

//These methods have the @GetMapping("***") Tag, inside of the parentheses, is the name that thymeleaf will use when calling to find that page-Explained more on the HTML pages
//The return "***"; references directly to the web pages names that are located in the src/main/resources/templates folder
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;
        
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String viewHomePage() 
        {
            return "index";
        }
        
        @GetMapping(value="/loginpage")
        public String login()
        {
            return "loginpage";
        }
        
        @GetMapping(value="/registration")
        public String register(Model model)
        {
            model.addAttribute("users", new Users());
            return "registration";
        }
        
        
        @GetMapping(value="/dashboard")
        public String dashboard()
        {
            return "dashboard";
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did this right: https://pastebin.com/DcjjgiWV

Comment: @Maya, since you're using Spring security 6, you may check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748003/unauthorized-error-full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resource-with

Comment: @Maya Why did you disable `@EnableWebSecurity`? Enable it and try again.

Comment: @dur Hi Dur we were just testing out a little bit of everything that could have been the issue. 
Our professor just suggested it had something to do with this line of code: 
"<form class="LoginCont" th:action="@{/loginpage}" method="post">"
But were still unable to find the correct solution to eliminate the error.

*EDIT: Also enabling it still gives that error as well.

Comment: @Maya What is happening if you call `/dashboard` without login first? Do you see your custom login page? Also add a `permitAll()` after `.formLogin()`, just to be sure.

Comment: @dur Hi again!
So if we do "http://localhost:8080/dashboard" it takes you to the dashboard page without login bypassing the custom login page.

Comment: @Maya Then your security configuration is not used. `/dashboard` is a secured path in your configuration. You should see the login page. Do you have any second security configuration on class path?

Comment: @dur So image it would be something like adding in multiple configurations, something like the link below: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the problem with this part:

```
.loginPage("/loginpage")
.loginProcessingUrl("/loginpage")
```

`loginPage` is the path your app uses as UI to input user's credentials
`loginProcessingUrl` is the path your app uses to process entered credentials from UI.

Try to change `loginProcessingUrl` to `"/login"` and change it in html:

```
<form class="LoginCont" action="/login" method="post">
```

(thymeleaf tag is not required)

Thus, your login page will be still available from `"/loginpage"`.

P.S. also add "/login" to permited request matchers.

Hope it will helps you.